# How to use vanilla JS to query with a single value a data attribute with array of values?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, custom-data-attribute

I have a series of blog posts that have an array of tags as a `data-tags` html attribute such as `["foo", "bar", "baz"]`. I'm looking to query the DOM elements that have `foo` included in the `data-tags` array.

Example markup:

```
<li data-tags="['foo', 'bar', 'baz']">...</li>
```

I know it's possible to query if the data attributes were stored as a singular value, ie:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-specifc-tag="foo"]');
```

Is it even possible to select elements which arrays include a specific value?

(Vanilla JS only, no jQuery please)

Comment: Can you show enough of your HTML that we can see exactly the type of content you need to search, and in response to what event(s)? Please read the [mcve] and [ask] guidelines as a refresher.

Comment: See css attribute selector documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp You might use `[data-tags~="foo"]` or `[data-tags*="foo"]` depending on your html.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that your HTML is invalid you can't delimit text within an attribute with the same delimiter that you use to quote the string; also: why is it an array within a string, rather than a white-space separated string of tags?

Comment: Interesting, the selector `*=` that @kLabz suggested seems to be working properly with existing markup. Nevertheless, thank you for pointing out that white-space separated string of tags is better practice. I will definitely use that implementation.

Comment: if `querySelectorAll` gets too slow, alternative is to loop all element and check their `.dataset.tag` property https://jsperf.com/queryselectorall-vs-getelementsbytagname

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sum up, the query you need is

```
document.querySelectorAll('li[data-tags*=\'"foo"\']')
```

But you have to make sure that each element in your html array is enlosed within double quotes. You may change it to a single quote, but make sure to update the query.

You can search for multiple queries by adding more rules as follows

```
document.querySelectorAll('li[data-tags*=\'"foo"\']'+'[data-tags*=\'"bar"\']')
```

Below is a snippet that applies those queries based on some value you may be interested in. I made sure to use the same html structure you put in your question.

**Edit:**

I added one more function, queryAll, that allows for value queries. So, you can search for elements that must have more than one value.

```js
function entry(search){
  var string = '"' + search + '"';
  return '[data-tags*=\'' + string + '\']';
}

function queryAll() {
  var queries = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).map(function(a){
    return '[data-tags*=\'' + a + '\']';
  });
  //example: document.querySelectorAll('li[data-tags*=\'"foo"\']');
  return document.querySelectorAll('li'+ queries.join(''));
}

function query(search) {
  var string = '"' + search + '"';
  //example: document.querySelectorAll('li[data-tags*=\'"foo"\']');
  return document.querySelectorAll('li[data-tags*=\'' + string + '\']');
}
query("foo1"); // One li
query("foo"); //Two li's

queryAll("foo1", "bar1");  //one li
queryAll("foo1", "bar1Not");  //nothing
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-tags='["foo", "bar", "baz"]'>...</li>
  <li data-tags='["foo1", "bar1", "baz1"]'>...</li>
  <li data-tags='["foo2", "bar2", "baz2"]'>...</li>
  <li data-tags='["foo", "bar2", "baz2"]'>...</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vanilla js solution to your problem:

```
const posts = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tags]');
const fooPosts = [];
posts.forEach(post => {
    if (/foo/.test(post.getAttribute('data-tags'))) {
        fooPosts.push(post);
    }
});

// output the filtered posts
console.log(fooPosts);
```

One liner alternative:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-tags]').forEach(post => /foo/.test(post.getAttribute('data-tags')) && console.log(post));
```

Or splitted:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-tags]').forEach(post =>
    /foo/.test(post.getAttribute('data-tags')) && console.log(post));
```

Please, note that, as mentioned in the comments, your html markup is invalid. Data attributes should not contain complex data structure like arrays or objects. As suggested, consider performing a .join() on your array data and outputting it in the attribute [data-tags] as a string. In it each value can be separated by comma for readability.

Using the valid markup your solution will be slightly different:

```
const posts = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tags]');
const fooPosts = [];
posts.forEach(post => {
    if (post.getAttribute('data-tags').indexOf('foo') > -1) {
        fooPosts.push(post);
    }
});

console.log(fooPosts);
```

The above code is also faster as it's using .indexOf() to filter the DOM nodes. 
Here's the above code in a reusable function:

```
const filterNodesByAttr = (attr, tag) => {
    let filtered = [];
    const items = document.querySelectorAll(`[${attr}]`);
    items.forEach(item => {
        if (item.getAttribute(attr).indexOf(tag) > -1) {
            filtered.push(item);
        }
    });
    return filtered;
};

const fooPosts = filterNodesByAttr('data-tags', 'foo');
console.log(fooPosts);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to get any element on the page.

I.e.

Get elements with href's `[href]`

Get divs with data-type of price  `div[data-type=price]`

```js
var attributes = ['data-rel','type'];
attributes.forEach((at)=>{
   document.querySelectorAll('['+at+']').forEach((element)=>{
      element.append('<b>'+at+'</b>');
   });
 });
```

```html
<p>Hello</p>
<p data-rel="title">World!</p>
<p type="emoji">:-)</p>
```